# tortoisegit push successfully, but no new files?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have setup a git repository in a linux server, and installed the latest MSysGit and TortoiseGit on my Windows 7 laptop.
I can pull from the remote repository by TortoiseGit, and I can commit & push to remote repository too.
If I run "git log" in the remote server, it can show the latest comments correctly. But the new files are missing in the remote server. Please advise and suggest. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is highly recommended that you never push to a *non-*bare repository. Instead, you should create a bare repository that is a clone of your remote repository. The laptop will push to the bare repository, then the remote repository will *pull* from the bare one.

If you push to the non-bare repository, you will sooner or later accidentally lose work.

Comment: why is that? with SVN if i understand is always pushing. You just need to update before doing the push. Why will you "sooner or later accidentally lose work."?

Comment: AFAIK github you must push. Isnt that no longer bare once you push something onto it? i actually dont understand why i can push to github repeatedly and not to my local repository.

Comment: @acidzombie24: First, SVN and Git work differently and there is no such thing as a "non-bare" SVN repository. Second, a Github repository is always considered "bare". In Git terminology, a "bare" repository is one that has *no working copy*. It does not mean that it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The index has been updated, but not the workspace. To update the workspace, use `git reset`. If you have uncommitted modifications, make sure to commit them, `git stash` them, or use `git reset --hard` if you don't mind losing them.

edit: Probably a moot point by now, but it looks like `git reset` by itself isn't enough - use `git reset --hard`.