# How do i create a local bare repository with tortoisegit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Greg's comment help me understand [tortoisegit push successfully, but no new files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698552/tortoisegit-push-successfully-but-no-new-files/1698657#1698657)

How do I create a local bare repository with tortoisegit?

I can right click and clone a repository from github and push. I would like to create a local repository then do the same thing, clone and push. How do I do that?

-edit- I have created a local repository just fine but I can't push to it. I need to pull everything. I like the consistency of pushing in both my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this feature, tracked by [tortoisegit issues 220](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/220), was fixed in Q4 2010, and is now part of the [TortoiseGit documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-create.html) with the "Make it Bare" option:

[image: http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tortoisegit-create-repository.png]
[image]
<sup>(Source: "[Getting started with Git on Windows](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/08/30/getting-started-with-git-on-windows/)" by **[Darran Jones](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/about/)**)</sup>

---

Original answer (2009)

You can create it manually (see [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_make_existing_non-bare_repository_bare.3F)), but [Issue 220](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/220) (November 2009, still opened in May 2010) mentions that TortoiseGit does not yet support that option.

So for now, it is:

```
$ mv repo/.git repo.git
$ git --git-dir=repo.git config core.bare true
$ rm -rf repo
```

or

```
$ ssh to remote server
$ git clone --bare -l <path_to_repos> <new_dir>
* renamed old repository directory
* renamed new repository dir to what old repository used to be.
```

Comment: Just released to internal testing Dec 2010
Release 1.5.9.0
Features * #220: Enhancement, support creating bare repositories

Answer (score 3):

Create an empty directory in explorer and then open the context menu. Select "Git -> Create repository here..." and check "Make it Bare".

The "Make it Bare" will be checked automatically when that folder is named something like "XXX.git".